# Why don't Projects folder and subfolders dynamically update with file system changes?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

After spending a long time debugging Sublime Text 2, I discovered the bug is in OSX.

The Finder does not dynamically update changes in the file system for the Projects folder and subfolders.

Why not?

How to fix?

OSX 10.7.5

EDIT: To clarify, when changing the file system in the terminal (for example touch tempfile or rm tempfile), the finder window updates immediately on most folders. However, in the Projects folder, the finder window does not update.

This is a problem with Sublime Text 2 because it has a files pane that updates as the file system changes. This does not work for folders inside the Projects folder. I thought it was a bug with Sublime Text 2. But it is a bug in OSX.

Comment: Are you saying that a Finder window's visual display of files/folders doesn't update as the file system does? If so, how is that related to Sublime Text?

Comment: What exactly is this Projects folder? Is this something specific to Sublime Text?

Comment: No, it is created automatically and is in the home folder.

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers: Sublime Text has a files panel on the left side of the GUI, that allows you to browse files in a standard tree structure. Usually this panel updates snappily to reflect any changes on the disk, but with this bug, the panel doesn't update to show newly added or renamed files. In B Seven's case (as in my case), Finder exhibits the same behavior -- hence the conclusion that this is not a Sublime bug, but a filesystem event issue with Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is the problem of Sublime Text as I am also using OSX 10.7.5 and have the same problem when viewing files and folders on a NAS (network server).

For some reason the Finder doesn't 'build' the folder/subfolder view as it used to on my earlier OSX 10.4.11 iMac - so it MUST be the newer operating system and Finder.

I have to force the Finder to quit and relaunch it for it to show me the up to date cached file system. It is causing me a real problem.

Comment: I actually had the same issue when working on remote files on a shared folder. Remote folders and the Projects folder don't update in real time.

Comment: Yes, it only seems to affect 'non local' or third party file systems. I don't have the problem when viewing contents of the hard drive.

Comment: Also, in my case,the 'non local' NAS filesystem is hosted by Windows and has to be accessed by 'SMB'on the mac - e.g Connect to server, then, SMB://10.0.0.4.

Comment: In my case, this problem occurs on my local FS, internal MBP hard drive. I have no external or virtual FS connected. However, my hard drive appears to be failing fast, and I assume that's the reason this glitch is happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't fix this in Sublime text 2, **but if** you are using Sublime Text 3, you can fix this same issue by installing a package called "SideBarEnhancements".